# How to compute reliability coefficient for a count things app?

Tags: image-processing, coefficients

I am currently trying to make an application that can count some objects in a container from a photo. I thought to include a reliability coefficient (trustworthiness) to alert if the photo and the output is clear or not, to give recommendations to change the input photo and then improve its output.

Naively, I thought of including some paramters (to specify whether the photo is clear or not)
like :

** The angle of the photo

** The distance since the photo was taken

** The brightness of the photo, the resolution etc.

Naively, each parameter will be between 0 and 1 and I will multiply all those parameters together to compute the reliability coefficient.

But when I quickly search for this coefficient, I found A LOT of things, like in statistics etc. And it scares me because I don't understand much about it and I don't have all the skills to understand it.

I just thought that a simple mathematical formula will be good, without using a statistical forumula...

Can you PLEASE help to understand how to compute such a coefficient ? Which formula I should use PLEASE ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Usually, such global parameters are not available nor very relevant. For instance, what is the "angle" ? How do you know it ? In what way does it make a picture bad ?

Comment: How do you plan to count the objects ?

Comment: For counting objects, I'll try to find a suitable "crowd counting" algorithm. For the others questions, as I said I'm not really sure about the algorithm I should use but the idea is to sélect some parameters that can help me to ignore bad pictures that will be useless for coutning or improving the picture

Comment: From a usability perspective you should overlay the object segmentation on the photo. That would be much easier to visually verify. Counting objects is much easier than giving an interpretation for a confidence measure.